# exFAT, NTFS, Windows, OSX support dilemma

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, ntfs, rsync

I have an external 2TB drive with 700GB used, the drive no longer shows up on my mac after the battery died on my mac whilst running an rsync backup to the drive. It appears exFAT has really poor support for OSX, I've had calls with Seagate and they recommend to not use exFAT, they apparently get issues with lost/corrupt data all the time due to exFAT.

so the drive works on windows. It doesn't show on OSX. So I have a new Ext HDD I want to move the data to with the most stable format for OSX.

I have the following in mind to do the data migration.

Windows PC
with ethernet to mac
with exFAT 2TB drive connected and windows SHARE enabled

MAC OSX
using rsync over the network to copy the data on the 2TB drive to my new extHDD with OSX Extended FS formatted.

thoughts? Long winded? whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not FAT32? It works on all.. unless you have some FAT32-related limitations that you don't like

Comment: FAT32 has limits on the number of elements in the root directory as well as the 4GB file size limit.

Comment: yeah I have 4.5GB files from my SLR :D

Comment: thinking I can simplify this by running ubuntu which seems to act as a good in-between Windows and OSX FS support. I can run ubuntu connect the two drives and have it rsync from one USB to the other.